# tableView adds extra (empty) cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS application which shows sessions in a UITableView. I'm currently in the phase of developing a custom tableviewcell to represent my data.

Based on the event type I'm changing the background color of a small bar in my tableviewcell (blue or orange). For some reason, the coloring is off and the tableview adds another cell which shouldn't be added. See image below.

[image]

Notice the first cell.. it has type: "ISKE" so should be orange, this is correct. Notice the second cell having the type: "ISKA". Now the bar on the right should've the color blue, which it is clearly not. It's weird though, because the font color of the date is in the correct color. Also notice the last bar being displayed, while there is no extra cell available.

I have no clue why this is happening. I hope someone can point me into the right direction.
My get cell method is as followed:

```cs
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    Session session = ObjectModel.Current.AllSessions.ElementAt (indexPath.Row);

    SessionTableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (session.SessionEvent.EventTitle) as SessionTableViewCell;

    if (cell == null) 
    {
        cell = new SessionTableViewCell ();
        var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("SessionTableViewCell", cell, null);
        cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as SessionTableViewCell;
    }

    if (session.SessionEvent.EventTitle == "ISKE") {
        cell.SessionEventColor = UIColor.FromRGB (255, 165, 0);
        cell.SessionDateFontColor = UIColor.FromRGB (255, 165, 0);
    } else {
        cell.SessionEventColor = UIColor.FromRGB (80, 124, 191);
        cell.SessionDateFontColor = UIColor.FromRGB (80, 124, 191);
    }

    cell.SessionDay = session.SessionDate.DayOfWeek.ToString ().ToUpper ();
    cell.SessionTime = session.SessionDate.ToString ("HH:mm");
    cell.SessionDate = session.SessionDate.Day.ToString ().ToUpper ();
    cell.SessionSpeaker = "testspeaker";
    cell.ImgBgView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB (206, 206, 208).CGColor;
    cell.ImgBgView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;

    cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
    cell.SessionTitle = session.SessionTitle;
    cell.SessionEvent = session.SessionEvent.EventTitle;
    cell.SessionRoom = session.SessionRoom;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your datasource, `UITableView` height and cell height specified.

Comment: cell height is 84px, which is the same as in my GetHeightForRow. My tableview height is 416px (full screen). Not sure why this would matter though?

Comment: I found the problem. I thought I was working with retina pixels.. so the border thingy was double the size of my table view cell which caused it to render double I guess. Prasad_R pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
cell = new SessionTableViewCell ();
var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("SessionTableViewCell", cell, null);
cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as SessionTableViewCell;
```

You don't have to call the constructor AND `LoadNib`. `LoadNib` should be enough. Calling both could lead to troubles. So your code should be:

```cs
var nibs = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("SessionTableViewCell", cell, null);
cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (nibs.ValueAt (0)) as SessionTableViewCell;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I also thought this was the problem, but sadly it's not. The problem still occurs. Again, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

your `LoadNib` usage looks wrong:

```cs
var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("SessionTableViewCell", cell, null);
```

that means the owner is cell on it's own. I'd do

```cs
var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("SessionTableViewCell", this, null);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again for the response. This didn't help either.